# Extracting a number from an XML node

Tags: html, xml, xpath, web-scraping

The best I do (so far) with XPath is to extract the following node:

```
<li class="List-guests">&#13;
<span class="icon guests"/>&#13;
3&#13;
</li>
```

I actually need just to extract the number 3.  Is there a way to do this in XPath?  I really don't want to start using some complicated regex if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use the text() function

Answer (score 0):

Both the normalized text following the `class="icon guests"` `span`,

```
normalize-space(//span[@class="icon guests"]/following-sibling::text())
```

and the normalized text of the `class='List-guests'` `span`,

```
normalize-space(//li[@class='List-guests'])
```

for your shown XML will be `3`, as requested.

**Note**: This is the string `3`.  You can wrap either of the above XPath expressions in `number()` if you actually need the number `3`.